# Windows Server 2012 external DNS not working

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, internal-dns

I have registered a domain name (example.com) through a registrar and have it configured well enough so that when I go to http://example.com from a remote pc I get my default website. When I go to https://example.com I get an Exchange Server web console I've installed. However, if I go to remote.example.com (http) I get sent back to my default website and same with remote.example.com (https) I get sent back to my exchange server -- basically the subdomain directs to whichever protocol is specified.

What I can't comprehend is I have it setup via DNS so that if I go to remote.example.com a webpage hosted on another server (as intended) shows -- this works when I do it on the server hosting the dns settings. It seems my internal dns works but it does not work externally.

I have searched and read and can't figure this out. Is there a book I should be reading? Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am new to this stuff and trying to learn.

Thank you for any guidance.

---

**Zone file export for @Damon:**

Name    Type    Data    Timestamp
_msdcs
_sites
_tcp
_udp
DomainDnsZones
ForestDnsZones

(same as parent folder) Start of Authority (SOA)    [65], exchange.example.com., hostmaster.example.com.    static

(same as parent folder) Name Server (NS)    exchange.example.com.   static

(same as parent folder) Host (A)    192.168.1.104   ?1/?11/?2015 6:00:00 PM

exchange    Host (A)    192.168.1.104   static

remote  Host (A)    192.168.1.121   static

www Alias (CNAME)   example.com.    static

Comment: can you provide us with the CName record for 'remote' of your domain at registrar as well as the DNS entry on your server for remote.example.com.

Comment: I edited question to hopefully include what you requested. I am hosting the DNS locally and have the registrar pointing to my servers ip.

Comment: From the remote that does nslookup say for remote.example.com does it show public IP that you have for this server?

Answer (score 0):

Users that access you webservers from the internet don't care about your internal servers.

Let's make an example for this scenario.

Example.com resolved by external DNS: 1.1.1.1 (just an example)
remote.example.com resolved by external DNS: 1.1.1.1

1.1.1.1:80 -> 192.168.1.104:80

Now you need to change the external dns for remote to 1.1.1.2 (and maybe you need to buy an additional public ip).

1.1.1.2:80 -> 192.168.1.121:80

After changing this, the two dns names route correctly.